# MySQL Arabic character support using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, character-encoding, arabic

I'm using C# with MySQL as Database server.
I'm facing problem with Arabic character support ! I've searched for ages but nothing.
Finally I got this [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/193480/MySql-and-C-and-arabic)(number 4) which seems to work perfectly but I get new error while run time says:

> Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x8A\xD8\xB3' for column 'name' at row 1

Anyone can help to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Much better if you add your solution as an answer, because this where the answer is supposed to be.

Comment: Moreover, it'd be better to write the answer rather than adding a link to another site, you can use it for reference, but the answer should be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is longtime ago the question has been asked but I think it will be very helpful to write down the answer for those who are facing same problem as me.
While creating new database in MySQL using workBench as I'm doing or even if you create it through commands you should specify the character collation type as `utf8` like in the picture
[image: creating database using MySQL workbench]

And pay attention that it should be `utf8_bin` because others may not work well !
then in C# also you should tell the connection to use `utf8` charset as following
`MySqlConnection sqlconn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=toor;CHARSET=utf8");`

Et volia it should work perfectly ;).